# Como configurar as credenciais de uma webRequest?

Tags: c#, webrequest

Como faço para realizar uma requisição em ASP NET MVC 5 dessa forma:

1. Method = post;
2. Credenciais de autenticação = xxx:yyyyyyy (ou seja, nome de usuário, seguido de dois pontos, seguido de password, criptografado no formato base64);
3. Enviar dados no **body** da webrequest no formato JSON.

Já realizei vários testes e gostaria de saber o que posso estar fazendo de errado

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(usernameAuth, passwordAuth, defaultURL);
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();

cache.Add(new Uri(defaultURL), "Basic", credential);
            
Console.WriteLine(cache);

/*
    var unEncodedString = String.Format("{0}:{1}", usernameAuth, passwordAuth);
    var encodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(unEncodedString));
*/

try
{
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(defaultURL);
                
    if (webRequest != null)
    {
        //webRequest.Credentials = cache;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webRequest.ContentLength = infoDados.Length;
        webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        webRequest.Credentials = cache;

        //enviando dados post
        using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(infoDados, 0, infoDados.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }

        //lendo dados
        using (Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Em meu código:

> `usernameAuth`: nome usuário da autenticação
>
> `passwordAuth`: senha senha da autenticação
>
> `defaultURL`: url de envio da request

Comment: a variavel defaultURL  está com o caminho completo de url e endpoint? se sim, tente colocar na defaultURL apenas o dominio que a aplicação está, o modo que você está criando a setando as credenciais está correto

Comment: Você quer mandar as credenciais onde? No corpo da requisição ou em algum header?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TENHO ALGO PARECIDO

```
 var resultObjects = JObject.Parse(json);//Converto a string para o formato json
            var jsonSerializado = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultObjects);//Serializo meu json
            var objeto = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(jsonSerializado);//Digo o formato do objeto para o serviço
            var requisicaoWeb = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://meuIp/01/fwmodel/PCP0012");//Digo o caminho da minha url aonde vou estar enviando meus dados
            requisicaoWeb.Method = "POST";
            requisicaoWeb.ContentType = "application/json";//Afirmo ao servidor que estou enviando os dados no formato apllication/json
            requisicaoWeb.ContentLength = jsonSerializado.Length;//Vê o tamanho dos dados que estão sendo enviados para o servidor
            requisicaoWeb.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BASIC d3NyZXN0aW50ZXJubzpnVXVAdmxsXnZ6ajVVOUd5aW9hbnZl");//Manda para o servidor a chave para poder acessa-lo
            requisicaoWeb.Timeout = 100000000;//Seta o tempo de timeout do servidor
            using (var stream = requisicaoWeb.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(objeto, 0, jsonSerializado.Length);//Lê o tipo do objeto e o seu tamanho para que assim o serviço entenda que dados estão chegando até ele
                stream.Close();//Fecha conexão com o servidor
            }
            try
            {
                var reposta = requisicaoWeb.GetResponse();//Caso ocorra alguma falha mostra o que está acontecendo
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```